# Detecting screen edges when moving UIImageView

Tags: iphone

I currently have a UIImageView which I can move/drag around the view.

How does on detect for the edge of the screen when the image moves and stop the image from being able to be moved out of the screens view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the rectangle of the `UIImageView` in the coordinates of your (outermost) view using

```
CGRect r = [iv convertRect:iv.bounds toView:self.view];
```

Then it's a matter of checking if `r` goes out of bounds, e.g. like this:

```
CGRect i = CGRectIntersect(r,self.view.bounds);

if ( CGRectIsNull(i) )
{
    NSLog(@"way out of bounds");
} else if ( !CGRectEqualToRect(i,r) ) {
    NSLog(@"partly out of bounds");
} else {
    NSLog(@"self.view envelopes imageview");
}
```

Of course, this should be put in your dragging code, with the `NSLog()` statements replaced with appropriate handling (e.g. by only updating location in the last case, or by translating the rect back into view if needed)

Comment: What should iv be? And I have the draggableItem in another class than the one I create it in. Could I not just hard code the CGRect for the view I want to box?

Comment: `iv` would be the pointer to your `UIImageView`. You could hardcode `iv.bounds` but it wouldn't solve any real problem - you need the pointer anyways for the `[iv convertRect:...]` call.