# Using View Frame when inside.

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, cgrectintersectsrect

I have an image view controlled by accelerometer and they are able to go out of the screen, how is it possible to detect if the image view is out of the screen and not visible to the user. I have tried using `CGRectIntersectsRect` and I also used `self.view.frame` but when my image view spawned it immediately detected it cause it was already in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `convertRect: toView:` and `CGRectIntersect` which will return `CGRect` and then you can compare both using `CGRectEqualToRect`

For sample you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290783/detecting-screen-edges-when-moving-uiimageview)